# Интерактивная карта с геокодированием (информация, привязанная к зданиям/адресам)

Tags: openstreetmap, геокодирование

Для внутренней информационной системы возникла необходимость работать с информацией, привязанной к обычным жилым домам.

Вывести карту тривиально — это умеет каждый первый. В частности, уже сейчас за пол-часа сделана карта домов, на базе OpenStreetMap/Leaflet, где каждый дом, для которого есть геотегированая запись в БД, отмечен маркером.

Проблема возникла в обратном геокодировании — как бы сделать возможным, чтобы пользователь кликнул по полигону-зданию на карте, и адрес этого объекта был распознан? Т.е. появляется «новый» (для компании) дом, который надо добавить в базу. Пользователь идет, кликает по дому, появляется панель добавления записи для дома по данному адресу. Если кликает не по дому, а по чему-то другому — ничего не происходит (т.к. объекта в этом месте нет).

Быстрым решением-костылем стало использование Nominatim, но результаты обратной геолокации по координатам оставляют желать лучшего, да и результат не ахти. Тыкаю в пустырь за городом, получаю адрес где-то в городе, причем даже толком непонятно где это такой (полигона-то не возвращается). Хочется же получить ответ или «не знаю тут ничего» или «тут объект building, адрес ему пока никто на OSM не приписал (не страшно, сами напишем и в OSM отправим правку), а вообще это многоугольник о 4 вершинах, координаты прилагаются.» В упор не могу найти в куче разрозненной документации ничего такого более-менее готового.

Есть, конечно, вариант — скачивать дамп OSM, запихивать в PostgreSQL с PostGIS, и, начитавшись документации, делать свой геокодер. Но наверняка я не первый с такими желаниями, и что-то уже есть более готовое, чем создание всего велосипеда с нуля.

Масштабы — маленький городок, грубо — до 10000 зданий. Вплоть до того, что можно нарезать по квадратам (грубо, 10x10), да делать все client-side. Запросов на геокодирование — до, наверное, пары десятков в особо урожайный день, т.е., сущие мелочи.

Да, Google Maps, Яндекс.Карты, 2ГИС — спасибо, не подходит, у них у всех лицензионное соглашение требует а) использование для открытого для всех сайта, а не внутренней корпоративной админки и б) жестко ограничивает возможности по использованию полученных с геокодера данных (считай, vendor lock-in).

Comment: Как выяснилось, выдрать все дома и представить в виде JSON-документа тривиально: [https://gist.github.com/4154170](https://gist.github.com/4154170)

Но метаданные домов на OSM скудны, а писать решение задачи «определить вхождение многоугольника (дома) в другой многоугольник (город)», хоть и не сложно, но зело лениво. Как и не сильно хочется трогать боевой PostgreSQL, доставляя туда PostGIS. Поэтому все еще жду советов мудрых, вдруг что более готовое есть.

Comment: Если не сильно хочется трогать боевой Постгрес (что вполне нормально), заведите тестовый.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже возникала подобная задача. Но у нас изначально был развёрнут PostgreSQL с PostGIS для хранения гео-данных.

Если нужно получить дом по координате для большого количества координат, то лучше просто выполнять запросы напрямую к базе данных. Найти попадание точки в геометрию и выбрать потом дома не сложно.

Если нужно получить дом из клиента (веб-браузера) при клике мышкой по карте, то OpenLayers и GeoServer позволяют получить необходимую информацию с помощью вызова WMSGetFeatureInfo(). Только нужно будет отфильтровать вывод и выбрать только дома.

В своё время смотрел различные системы для обратного геокодинка, но для моих задач оказалось гораздо проще во всех планах использовать описанный выше подход.

В вашем случае свой геокодер, как вы выразились, сведётся к написанию пары запросов к базе. Так что рекомендую настроить PostGIS, загрузить туда только свой город и периодически обновлять его.

Кстати, править боевой PostgreSQL не обязательно. Даже лучше будет, если для гео-данных настроить отдельную базу.

Answer (score 0):

Есть сервис по адресу http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse.php?format=json&json_callback=renderExampleThreeResults&lat=50.597567&lon=36.5577654

Документация http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/

Answer (score 0):

Примерно полгода назад пришлось решать такую же проблему. Готовых решений найти не удалось. Пришлось делать самостоятельно, начав с решения обратной задачи: с получения от OSM и сохранения в своей базе полигонов для всех адресов в городе. Далее эти полигоны загружались в память в виде [R-дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Точнее, не сами полигоны, а прямоугольники, в которые они вписаны. Поиск по такому дереву позволяет эффективно находить эти прямоугольники, после чего нужно проверить попадание уже непосредственно в полигон.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение, ищет по провайдеру на выбор (bing, google, nokia, osm):

L.Control.GeoSearch - search for an address and zoom to its location
https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch